# Cannot get object values using *ngFor="let admin of admins" in angular 2

Tags: angular

[this is my admins array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcLzu.png) Cannot get object values using *ngFor="let admin of admins" in angular 2. I am able to get the values in typescript and display in console, but in html table using *ngFor am getting only empty rows. this is the html template.  [this is what I am getting in table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkUOj.png)

```
<tr *ngFor="let admin of admins">

                      <td style= "padding:0px;padding-top:5px;"><p style="font-size:13px;"><a href="#" onclick="return false;">{{admin.id}}</a></p></td>
                      <td style= "padding:0px;padding-top:5px;"><p style="font-size:13px;">{{admin.name}}</p></td>
                      <td style= "padding:0px;padding-top:5px;"><p style="font-size:13px;">{{admin.username}}</p></td>
                      <td style= "padding:0px;padding-top:5px;"><p style="font-size:13px;">{{admin.email}}</p></td>
                      <td style= "padding:0px;padding-top:5px;"><p style="font-size:13px;">{{admin.phone}}</p></td>
                      <td style= "padding:0px;padding-top:5px;"><p style="font-size:13px;"><a href="#" onclick="return false;">chat</a></p></td>

              </tr>
```

Comment: What type of values your `admins` contains?

Comment: Please link your `.ts` file where you instantiate `admins`

Comment: just type {{admin | json }} and check if there is any result

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What does "I am able to get the values in type" mean?

Comment: @MuhammadAlbarmawi using {{admin | json }} i am able to print one entire object in one division. But i want individual values of attributes in divisions

Comment: @NicoHaase edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value contains json string not json object so you need to pares to json object using `JSON.parse`